# Flutter: Downwards curved custom appbar with ClipPath

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Hey I have a custom Appbar and I want it to look like this:

[image: mockup]

So far I have successfuly created a custom app bar and clipped it with `ClipPath` to get a special form:

```
return ClipPath(
  clipper: WaveClip(),
  child: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: preferredSize,
    child: Container(
      color: getAppBarColor(),
      child: Column(
        ...
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

But I have failed to create this exact app bar. My clip form looks like this:

```
class WaveClip extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    double height = size.height;
    double width = size.width;
    double curveHeight = size.height / 2;
    var p = Path();
    p.lineTo(0, height - curveHeight);
    p.quadraticBezierTo(width / 4, height, width/2, height - curveHeight);
    p.lineTo(width, 0);
    p.close();
    return p;
  }
...
```

This results in some ugly wave like appbar. Is there any online tool that creates `ClipPaths` for me? I don't really want to have to bother with mathemical functions to create custom shapes  If not can anyone help me out with this? Thanks.

Comment: I think you can follow @William Verhaeghe answer, instead of using clipper in this.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I would like to clip it in case the client has any more funny ideas. The previous appbar was also clipped. Also the background might be a different color depending on the screen. So it really needs to be clipped/transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using `CustomClipper`, you can follow this

```dart
class WaveClip extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    double curveHeight = size.height / 2;
    var p = Path()
      ..lineTo(0, size.height)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(0, curveHeight, curveHeight, curveHeight)
      ..lineTo(size.width - curveHeight, curveHeight)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width, curveHeight, size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0);

    return p;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

And use

```dart
ClipPath(
  clipper: WaveClip(),
  child: Container(
    height: 200,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
    alignment: Alignment(0, -.5),
    color: Colors.amber,
    child: Text("sdsdsd"),
  ),
),
```

[image]

You can check more about [cubic-bezier-curves-with-svg-paths](https://medium.com/@bragg/cubic-bezier-curves-with-svg-paths-a326bb09616f) and also check [bezier.method.ac](https://bezier.method.ac/) site.

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer. Weird that there isn't a tool for that and you have to write the function yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than clipping a path, you can create this effect using a Container with rounded borders

```dart
Container(
      height: 32,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.black,
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(32),
          topRight: Radius.circular(32),
        ),
```

You can then, if you'd like, create a nice scroll animation using a CustomScrollView with a SliverAppBar.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to clip it in case the client has any more funny ideas.  The background might be a different color depending on the screen. So it really needs to be clipped/transparent.